# OpenSUSE php-fpm.conf permission denied

Tags: php, nginx, opensuse, fpm

I cannot launch php-fpm on OpenSUSE.
When I run `systemctl restart php-fpm.service`
I receive the following error, after copying `etc/php8/fpm/php-fpm.conf.default` to `etc/php8/fpm/php-fpm.conf`

```
[25-Apr-2021 12:52:18] ERROR: failed to open configuration file '/etc/php8/fpm/php-fpm.conf': Permission denied (13)
[25-Apr-2021 12:52:18] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/etc/php8/fpm/php-fpm.conf'
[25-Apr-2021 12:52:18] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to switch to php7-fpm to make it works.
It seems that php-fpm does not work properly on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed.

No problem with apache mod php.

Answer (score 0):

### I had some of the issues as can be found in your post.

My setup:
php8 with nginx (fast-cgi NOT USING SOCK) works fine on my laptop
**hardware**:               HP mobile workstation Compaq 8510w

- Yes, I know, that is not the latest gear, but its very solid and stable.
  It looks like it has been made for Linux!
  Micros....urged me to upgrade it from W7 to W10
  but left me alone with unsolvable issues. Their Troubleshooter told me
  "Ask a friend" and that is what I did.
  The friend said, try linux and that is why I am here now.
  I never regretted and this is the only reason to say "Thank you Micros..."

Operating System:       openSUSE Tumbleweed 20210
KDE Plasma Version:     5.22.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.85.0
Qt Version:             5.15.2
Kernel Version:         5.13.8-1-default (64-bit)
Graphics Platform:      X11
Processors:             2 × Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T9300 @ 2.50GHz
Memory:                 3.8 GiB of RA
Graphics Processor:     AMD RV630

**for peace of mind:**

- nginx and php have numerous safety-features.
  Safety is very important, so keep an eye on the common IT-safety rules,
  but be aware, that safety-rules can lock you out, if not implemented correctly.
  Before doing any editing make backups of all original configuration files

**for convenience:**

I installed mc (Midnight Commander) and use nano as editor.
I added myself to the group wheel, so that I can use sudo without having to enter my password.
mc is very convenient for changing directories, jumping from file to file and editing configuration files, because you can use mc as root.     Besides that you can easily change to the shell and back i.E to modify permissions or to use other shell-commands.
Further:
I created aliases in .bashrc enabling starting, stopping and checking
services with shortcuts.

```
alias sto='sudo systemctl stop $2'    
alias str='sudo systemctl start $2'    
alias rst='sudo systemctl restart $2'          
alias sta='sudo systemctl status $2'    
alias sn='sudo nano $2'
```

How to use them?
After editing your .bashrc do a

```
source .bashrc
```

To use these aliases you type the aliasname, a blank and the path to the file like for example for editing a file als sudo with nano try:

```
sn /etc/rc.local
```

or, to retrieve the status of php-fpm with just a few keystrokes:

```
sta php-fpm
```

I copied /etc/php8/php.ini to "php.ini.commented" and deleted all comments and non required options in the original
I also copied /etc/php8/**cli**/php.ini to php.ini.commented and deleted all
comments and non required options in the original
I did the same with /etc/php8/fpm/php-fpm.d/www.conf

**for avoiding conflicts:**

Before any other software operation, make sure that your system is running without errors.
Use

```
dmesg -l err
```

or

```
journalctl -b |grep error
```

Solve found errors first!
After verification you should execute a

```
sudo zypper dup
```

- do not change more than 1 parameter per trial, when testing/modifying your configuration.
  Check for result of modifications in logfiles after each step.
- write comments in the modified config and -if using an advice from a website- paste the web-address as a comment since in a few days you might not remember why you configured as you did.
- avoid multiple blanks in comments in configuration files, this can lead to a "parse error".
  I use the pathnames as they are being configured by setup.
  Do it like this, it will prevent problems after software-updates.
  I did **not** use the original Tumbleweed user/group "wwwrun" and "www",     instead I created a user "www-data" in group "www-data" exactly as in Raspberry debian 10.

with following commands

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /srv    
sudo chmod -R 755 /srv
```

I have changed ownership and permissions of all contents, that will be accessed by php-fpm.

In case you place symlinks in /srv/www/public to files elsewhere, you need to change the permissions in the files, the link is pointing to.     For example if you create a symlink in /srv/www/public to your phpmyadmin data, you need to change the permissions for all files in /usr/share/mysql/phpmyadmin.
The user of the data in your pool /srv/www/public **must be the same** as the user, defined in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, and
when using a pool named "public", user and group in the section [public] in /etc/php8/fpm/php-fpm.d/www.conf **must also be the same** .
This is crucial, most problems at startup of nginx are caused by wrong permissions.

**STEP BY STEP**

- Begin with a basic setup, without any special features.
  On request of friends I added my functional configuration files below
- Do not copy configurations from it-specialists in the web, who might do complicated or exotic things, proxies, remote servers etc.
  Especially if in those configurations there are expressions you don't understand , better don't use them.
- Just get started, undo temporary solutions as soon as nginx is operational and make a backup of the first working basic configuration.
  After that -but not earlier- you can start experimenting
- Never use chmod 777 in any of the above directories, because that's is an invitation to get your system hacked.
- Never change the mod 644, owner root:root in /var/log
  The logfiles of php-fpm are being created and modified by root. Logfiles contain sensitive info.
- Verify correct setup with:

```
ps -aux |grep php
```

The result should be similar to following lines. This means that php-fpm is being run by root:
root      1262  0.0  0.3  54024 13260 ?        Ss   06:12   0:01 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php8/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data  1335  0.0  0.2  54172  9576 ?        S    06:12   0:00 php-fpm: pool public

Allowing access to anybody else is opening the doors for hackers. Keep in mind that you are using a browser to see your data, but other people may be able to browse them as well.

After having a running system it is easy to add further steps.
To start up there is **no need for using sites-enabled** in nginx
and you need to create **just one pool** in /etc/php8/fpm/php-fpm.d/www.conf

**TROUBLESHOOTING FREQUENT ERRORS:**

- MySql-errors:
  I presume here, that your mariadb/mysql has been setup correctly.
  Missing or wrong permissions will cause "not found" errors.
  Troubleshooting in mysql is documented very well and mysql has an interactive help function. Read the documentation and test access following steps of the mysql manuals. It would lead too far, to add a guide for that to this document.
- php-fpm not starting:
  failed to open configuration file '/etc/php8/fpm/php-fpm.conf': Permission denied (13)

With

```
sudo systemctl status php-fpm
```

you will find more details about what and how.
Possibly there is an access-issue when php-fpm tries creating a logfile "access.public.log" in /var/log by following the line access.log = "access.$pool.log" (look in file www.conf).
This error can be caused/suppressed by settings in apparmor.
Options are:

- **temporary** disable apparmor

```
sudo systemctl stop apparmor
sudo systemctl disable apparmor
```

- In openSUSE You can use Yast to configure apparmor

[image: YAST]

In case you made modifications the result can be found as below in:

```
/etc/apparmor.d/php-pfm
```

---

```
 vim: ft=apparmor


profile php-fpm /usr/sbin/php-fpm* flags=(attach_disconnected, complain) {
    include <abstractions/base>
    include <abstractions/nameservice>
    include <abstractions/openssl>
    include <abstractions/php>
    include <abstractions/ssl_certs>
    include if exists <local/php-fpm>
    include if exists <php-fpm.d>

    capability chown,
    capability dac_override,
    capability kill,
    capability net_admin,
    capability setgid,
    capability setuid,

    signal send peer=php-fpm//*,

    deny / rw,

    /etc/php8/fpm/php-fpm.conf r,
    /etc/php{,5,7}/* r,
    /usr/sbin/php-fpm* rix,
    owner /var/log/php*-fpm.log rw,
    owner /var/log/public.acess.log rw,
    @{PROC}/@{pid}/attr/{apparmor/,}current rw,
    @{run}/php{,-fpm}/php*-fpm.pid rw,
    @{run}/php{,-fpm}/php*-fpm.sock rwlk,
    owner /etc/php8/fpm/php-fpm.d/www.conf r,

    change_profile -> php-fpm//*,

}
```

---

- or **temporary** comment the line
  access.log = /var/log/$pool.access.log in your www.conf
  To get started this file is not absolutely required
  and commenting it helped me to suppress the **"php-fpm could not be started"** error.
  The most important and detailed logfile is

  ```
    /var/log/nginx/error.log
  ```

  To debug, after every modification You should use

  ```
    sudo tail -1 /var/log/nginx/error.log
  ```

  You will see that most errors are permission errors either because mysql can't access your database or php-fpm can't use your php/html-files!

---

here my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

---

```
user www-data;                    
worker_processes auto;
#pid /run/nginx.pid;   not required when using tcp

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
  use epoll;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    include /etch/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;
        root /srv/www/public;        # without this root instruction nqinx will use /usr/ as prefix and you will get a not found error!    
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html; # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html    

        location = /50x.html {
          root   /srv/www/htdocs/;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {  # 404
          try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
          include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;  
      #   default fastcgi_params
      #   fastcgi settings
          fastcgi_pass          127.0.0.1:9000;
          fastcgi_index         index.php;
          fastcgi_buffers         8 16k;
          fastcgi_buffer_size       32k;
      #   fastcgi params
          fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT   /srv/www/public;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
          fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        location / {
          root   /srv/www/public;
          try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
          index index.nginx-debian.html index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root concurs with nginx's one
          deny  all;
        }
        include vhosts.d/*.conf;
    }
}
```

---

filecontents of /etc/php8/fpm/php-fpm.d/www.conf

---

```
[public]
prefix = /srv/www/$pool
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

;use these settings only if a socket is used
;listen.owner = www-data
;listen.group = www_data
;listen.mode = 0660

pm = static
pm.max_children = 1
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
pm.max_requests = 500

; this optional feature is well documented in the file and further instructions for how to set it up can be found on the web 
pm.status_path = /status

; if fpm-phm cannot start, temporary comment the two lines access.log, but reactivate the instructions as soon as php-fpm is operational
; if there are wrong permission-settings, php-fpm will not start  

access.log = /var/log/$pool.access.log
access.format = "%R - %u %t \"%m %r%Q%q\" %s %f %{mili}d %{kilo}M %C%%"

catch_workers_output = yes
security.limit_extensions = .php .html

env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
env[TMP] = /tmp
env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
env[TEMP] = /tmp
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 32M
```

---

file /etc/php8/fpm/php-fpm.conf

---

```
; FPM Configuration ;

[global]
process_control_timeout = 10
process.max = 128
daemonize = no
rlimit_core = 0
rlimit_files = 1024
events.mechanism = epoll
systemd_interval = 10

include=/etc/php8/fpm/php-fpm.d/*.conf
```

---

With this configuration I run several mysql-databases and content management as well as phpmyadmin.
The picture below is a screenshot of my Content Management System using a mysql database and self-designed forms in php-format.
In the location definitions there are **no further instructions required**, neither for loading stylesheets nor for pictures/movies.

[image: CMS Mythings]

A check with Google's developer tools in Chrome proofs, that all references and links to stylesheets, json-files and further directories have been found and that there are no errors.

[image: Chrome Tools]

Of course it took me some time to get all this running.
This answer may help everybody who wants to set up nginx and save time.
The documentation of nginx and php is complete and excellent. For most commands there is a --help option, man pages and a webpage.....

```
Yes, I know!    
  Help and man-pages are written by excellent IT-engineers,    
  some of these hexadecimal-thinking people might have difficultes    
  to translate their digital slang to human-understandable language.    
  That's why some pages are more confusing than helping.   
  Anyway, press the F1-key, try the help and forgive them.    
  Where would we be without them?
```

In my little network here, I am using a 24/7 running Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with 64 bit OS as server, that stores data on two USB drives.
The configuration for accessing local files on this server is nearly the same as the configuration on my laptop.
There are just two little differences:

On "debian buster" the application php8 is named php8.0 and a few directories have different names, so **you can use above configuration files for Raspberry debian buster with the following restriction**: the pertinent 'include' lines are different and need to be altered according to the location-names of the config-files .
My nginx.conf on the Raspberry-server has a few lines of extra code, in order to enable access to contents via DDNS, but that is a different chapter.

I would like to emphasize that I am not an IT-specialist. I have collected some experience in computing during my professional activities as mechanical engineer, all further know-how came from pressing the F1-key, reading forum-contributions, manuals, helpfiles, webpages and -not to forget- from made mistakes.
I hope that this may encourage others, to keep trying. Linux is structured very clearly and can be understood easily. Google errors, watch your logfiles attentively and enjoy the fun of finally running a fully operational php-fpm/nginx.
**I need to remind you once more:

Don't forget to reset all temporary solutions.**
​
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is related to apparmor settings. Please edit `/etc/apparmor.d/php-fpm`:

```
19   /etc/php{,5,7,8}/** r,
```

to allow access to directory `/etc/php8/` by `php-fpm` process.

Comment: I tried a new adventure with the opensuse Leap15.4Beta.    
After uncounted efforts I got phpMyAdmin started but the 50 added lines in Apparmor ate too much memory, so I removed Apparmor. Now all is perfect and is conform with my here published version for LEAP15.3